# How to store global state in Django application outside database?

Tags: python, django

I want to implement a neural network model in Django application so that it can communicate via REST API with other application. Django application iteratively (1) collects a batch of training data from the other application, (2) retrains the model on so far aggregated data and (3) gives predictions on demand from that other application. Time is crucial factor here. How and where can I store an instance of the trained model between those steps?

Comment: Try a module level variable and most importantly a single worker process deployment.

Comment: Why not in a file?

Comment: There will be lots of prediction demands. File smells like too time-consuming.

Comment: The only viable option to store persistant state (for a web application I mean) is a "database" of some sort - unless you're the only one using your wesite, you WILL have to handle multiple concurrent processes, so you have to use some way to  share your data between processes in a way that handle concurrent access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use a (SQL) database you can also use [Django's caching framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/cache/) to store nearly any kind of data that is somehow serializable. It offers a quite simplte and convenient API (`cache.set()`/`cache.get()` and you can use backends like memcached and redis (which could also be stored to disk). For more complicated use cases you might be looking into using redis with its own API which enables you to do more complicated stuff than when accessing it trough the caching API. Using these possiblities you can also share data between multiple processes/workers.